# Is there a way to prevent xlwings from writing columns from a SQL Query to my Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy, xlwings

I am using the `xlwings` library, `pandas`, and `sqlalchemy` to work with and read from a SQL Server Database and write to Excel spreadsheets.

When I write to an existing spreadsheet that already has column names in the first row, it is including the column headers from the SQL query, so that I have 2 rows with column names.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Here is my code:

```
engine = sa.create_engine(connection_url)

qry = "SELECT ID, GameTitle, GameType, GamePublishDate, GameStatus, TagType FROM game.tagNames"
with engine.connect() as con:
    rs = con.execute(qry)

df = pd.read_sql_query(qry, engine)

app = xw.App(visible=False)
wb = xw.Book("tags.xlsx")
ws = wb.sheets['TagNames']

ws.range('A2').options(index=False).value = df

wb.save()
wb.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent xlwings from writing the column names by adding `header=False` to the options.

For example, if you change this line:

```
ws.range('A2').options(index=False).value = df
```

to

```
ws.range('A2').options(index=False, header=False).value = df
```

The `header=False` part will stop it from writing column names.

[Documentation](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/datastructures.html#pandas-dataframes)